# How to wrap a database value with a div class?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm using a for loop to iterate through the rows in my dataset, and its printing it out to the screen, but I was wondering how to wrap the values with css? The code I'm using to dynamically create my table is

```
test.GetSubjects();
        int subjectid = 0;

        // Current row count.
        int rowCtr;// = 0;
        // Total number of cells per row (columns).
        int cellCtr;
        // Current cell counter.
        int cellCnt;

        //count number of rows in dataset
        int rN = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        cellCnt = 3;


        for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rN; rowCtr++)
        {
            // Create a new row and add it to the table.
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);

            for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= 3; cellCtr++)
            {

                // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();


                /* If the rowcounter is equal to the record numbers
                 * then it has to break because if not it will throw an error
                 * saying that there is no row at ending position */

                if (rowCtr == rN)
                    break;

                string myStr = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr -1]["SubjectName"].ToString();

                tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(myStr));

                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                rowCtr++;
                /* If the cellcount is 3 then it needs to break, if not then 
                 * you'll miss every 4rth record, don't know why. But this works */

                if (cellCtr == 3)
                {
                    rowCtr = rowCtr - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

and with each value I need to wrap in css, this is the css I want to use to wrap each value

```
border-style: solid;
border: 1px solid lightblue;
width: 58px;
height: 27px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color:lightblue;
```

the reason is I'm turning the values into links and want to add style to it. I guess I could add the style to the cells that's being generated, but since I did this in code behind I don't know how I would do it.

Comment: If they all should have the same css, why don't you just use a class?

Comment: The css is a class, I just forgot to add that...Its #MyDbValues.

Comment: Have you tried tCell.CssClass = myClass?

Comment: @jac Actually no I haven't, I'll try that now..

Comment: ps: if you start your for loops at 0 and use `<` instead of `<=`, i.e. `for (x=0; x<limit; x++) {...}` you'll avoid the off-by-one handling you're having to do..

Comment: @jac that worked!, Thank you if you want to make that an answer then please do..

Comment: @thebjorn, excellent idea. I don't like using the off by one handling, now that you mentioned this then I'm going to go your route instead of the off by one

Answer (score 1):

Add the HTML formatting to your myStr object.
string myStr = "**" + test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr -1]["SubjectName"].ToString() + "**"; for example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just outputting the text as

```
string myStr = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr -1]["SubjectName"].ToString();

tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(myStr));
```

You could instantiate a span object, add the class to the class property of the span object and then add the span object to the cell controls collection as you already are.

```
  var span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
span.InnerHtml = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr -1]["SubjectName"].ToString();
span.Attributes["class"] = "myCssClass";
tCell.Controls.Add(span);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using ASP.NET, I strongly consider you use the Razor engine if it is available to you. Currently you're doing it the hard way.

Here's a sample of how it would look in Razor assuming you really do need to wrap each value in a DIV:

```
<table>
  @foreach(DataRow row in test.dsSubjects.Rows)
  {
    <tr>
      <td><div class="myCssClass">@row["Field1"]</div></td>
      <td><div class="myCssClass">@row["Field2"]</div></td>
      <td><div class="myCssClass">@row["Field3"]</div></td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

It really does simplify things a lot.

Comment: I really want to get into using razor but I'm confused with the MVC.

Comment: Follow some of the tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc and you'll be in heaven in no time. I expect within a week you'll be helping others do the same.

Comment: I've gotten a couple books on the MVC, but can never find anything on transitioning from web forms to MCV. I try looking at MVC as a class, markup and code behind but I think I'm looking at it the wrong way

Comment: @user2970223 That's like looking for something on the transition from crawling to flying, they are so different in many functional ways that there is no point comparing. Here's my version: Your controller covers a group of related Actions (each action+view is like a WebForm). The View is (mostly) just the HTML/CSS/JavaScript for each action. The Model is the data translated into a format easiest for the View to consume (and sometimes pass back again).